Does the average income in the US drop by $9,500 if you exclude the ten richest Americans?
A leftist friend of mine shared this meme:


Averages are tricky like that

The average income in the United States is 74,500$.
Excluding the top 10 Americans, it's only 65,000.
Excluding the top 50, it drops to 48,000$.
Excluding the top 1,000, it drops to just 35,500$


It alleges that the average income in the United States drops by $9,500 if you exclude the ten richest Americans, $25,000 if you exclude the 50 richest, and $39,000 if you exclude the 1,000 richest.
Is this true?

Is this meme widely shared, or is its claim widely believed? It's unclear presently whether this meets the site's notability guidelines. Can you find the original post (or at the very least, a copy of the meme that's been widely viewed)?

@F1Krazy I tried to find the source for the image, because I saw it somewhere on Reddit in the last few days, but I wasn't able to find that post anymore. A Google Lens search for exact matches find some Thread posts from June, so I guess it originated there.

This is false because the "starting" value used by the meme is the median value, not the mean, of household income in the United States (as seen in this chart Real Median Household Income in the United States, showing $74,580 for 2022)
The reductions are made as though that value was an average, not a median.  While excluding outliers can change an average substantially, it affects the median only very slightly.
It also appears that the ostensible reductions from excluding the "top" earners are based on counting total wealth, not yearly income-- which is itself at least an order-of-magnitude error.  The 10 highest income Americans do not average $95,000,000,000 in annual income.
From the chart Mean Family Income in the United States you can see that mean family income (as opposed to median) is actually 126,500.  This is income and not wealth, but even if we are as generous as possible to the original graphic and assume we can just deduct total wealth of the top X, we see that excluding the top 10 reduces the mean to $116,000, and reducing the top 1,000 reduces to $87,000.  As percentage reductions, these are much less dramatic-- and the resulting mean is still higher than the (all but unchanged) median.  But remember, even these values are comparing apples (income) to oranges (total wealth)-- the total share of annual income going to the very wealthiest is much smaller.

@JiminyCricket.If you interpret "Average" as median, excluding the top 1,000 would not change it more than a few cents.

@JiminyCricket.- No, it's false.  If it's about the median, the magnitude of the change is wrong.  If it is about the mean, the starting value is wrong (plus the unrealized capital gains issue).  Either way, a key piece of information in the graphic is false.

You say $74,500 is the median, but that doesn't prove the claim false; conceivably, the mean could also be near that value. To check the claim we need to know what the mean actually is.

@NateEldredge true, but if they were close in value, then it would be very unlikely the median of all is double the mean of almost all.

In response to comments, I found the equivalent chart with actual mean family income so you can do a proper comparison.

+1 after the most recent edit. All the information is there to say that this is false, though it could perhaps use some rewording with the new info.

Interestingly the answer is almost “yes”, for the absolute amount the incomes drop by, except that the starting values are completely wrong in the original meme (since it used median instead of mean).

@fyrepenguin - But to consider the absolute amounts accurate, you would be subtracting total wealth from yearly income, which is itself highly dishonest.

Total personal income is $24 trillion.  https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PI#:~:text=Download,2024%207:43%20AM%20CDT Population is 337 million.  Average income is therefore $71,000.

Also CBP estimates 271 million as the noninstitutionalized adult population; $24 trillion/271 million is $88,561. Note the answer states family income not individual. @DavePhD

"even if we are as generous as possible to the original graphic and assume we can just deduct total wealth of the top X" - this is way too generous, and evidently misled at least @fyrepenguin. As you note yourself, net worth and annual income are wildly different. Even if we take a broad definition of "income" which includes unrealised gains, rich businessmen's net worths took them a probably-decades-long career to accrue, so you should expect this approach to overestimate the impact of removing them, probably by a factor of 10x or more (though it depends on how bursty the gains are).

(+1) This is useful and intuitively I think the conclusion is generally right but the original meme wasn't specifically about household income. It could be interesting to look at personal income or at least highlight the distinction in the answer.

@Relaxed the original meme confuses income with wealth (in order to make the math works, as the answer points out) so unfortunately no useful information can be extracted here.

@DanGetz The example I frequently use is that the mean number of Y chromosomes per person in the US is 0.5 and the median is 0.0, means and medians can end up very different

@uberhaxed Yes, I read the comments but this is rather orthogonal to my point.

Wealth increase of the top 10 might be a better number than taxable income if someone wants this done right

@DanGetz for the median of all to be the double the median of all minus 1000 you would need there to be only 500 people that make between the median of all and it's half. I.e. roughly half the population would have to be making <35500 and the other half would have to be making >74500 with only 500 individuals making money between those two values. This is actually interesting since it says less about income inequality than I would expect, though it makes sense if you think about it.

Average and median are different things, OP says average, answer talking about median is per definitionem NAA.

Both mean and median are averages (as are several other possible measures of central tendency)

@RoddyoftheFrozenPeas q significant proportion of households have more than one noninstitutionalized adult.

The income of individuals is confidential; however, Propublica says they obtained secret IRS information and published the income of the top 400 individuals for 2013-2018.  This is gross income before tax deductions. Generally, the list includes spousal income unless tax returns were separately filed.  Propublica stated in 2022 "All numbers were adjusted for inflation".
Bill Gates $2.85B
Michael Bloomberg $2.05B
Jan Koum $1.93B
Ken Griffin $1.68B
Laurene Powell Jobs $1.57B
Jeffrey Yass $1.30B
David Siegel $1.17B
John Overdeck $1.17B
Larry Ellison $1.07B
Steve Ballmer $1.05B
Total: $15.84 Billion
The US population was 331,449,281 in 2020, so removing the top 10 would reduce the average income by $48.
Adult population was 258.3 million, so removing the top 10 would reduce the average adult income by $61.
Number of households was 126.8 million, so removing the top 10 would reduce the average household income by $125.

Those "income" values are nonsense; they represent "how much did they choose to get taxed this year" not an actual measure of how much money they earned.

@Yakk If anything, that makes things even worse, since their actual incomes will be higher and removing them causes the averages to drop even more.

@Yakk the Propublica website goes into annual wealth increase also, but if you apply that standard to the top 10, you'd need to apply it to everyone.  Increase in home value is a big factor.  Also, apparent wealth increase includes lots of inflation.

@DavePhD You can use constant dollars for that.  The nice thing about doing total wealth increase is that you can get "net US assets" from one year, subtract the previous year, and divide by population.

@Yakk should use net worth of households, https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BOGZ1FL192090005Q 152 trillion as of Q1 2024.  Only about 1% is that of the top 10 households.

@DavePhD I honestly don't care about "households", I care about people.  How they arrange themselves in houses is not really that important; a house with 100,000$ and 12 people is poorer than one with 10,000$ and 1 person as far as I care.  Ideally, I'd care about a mixture of net worth and income, but that is harder to express.

@Yakk the total wealth of all the households equals the total wealth of all people. 152 trillion.

If the original question had instead been about wealth instead of income, one piece of the claim would be vaguely true:
Average wealth per household was $1.1M in 2022. There are around 130m households in the US in total, giving a total wealth of $143 trillion. The 10 wealthiest individuals have a combined wealth of around $1.2 trillion. So if one excludes them, the average household wealth is around 1% or $10,000 less, these $10,000 are presumably the same as quoted in the original question.
By similar computations, excluding the 50/1000 wealthiest households reduces the average wealth per household by $25,000/ $40,000. This is not too surprising if one looks at the median wealth per household, which is $141,000 (same source).

Average wealth per person is $371,771.77 (that deals with "people get married but lose 25% of their wealth, suddenly country gets richer" artifacts).  Top 400 (Forbes 400) have a total worth of 4.5 trillion; that shaves off a mere $13,500 (3.6% of the entire USA's net worth).

Of course, median net household net worth worth is rather lower, and even that conceals some substantial disparities (e.g. that a good quarter of the USA has 0 or negative net worth).

@Obie2.0 One should expect median networth to be lower than mean networth but seeing how big the difference actually is, is still quite shocking. Similarly, noting that taking out 10 households out of something like 100 million makes a visible difference shows how unequal the distribution is.

Arguably the median is more shocking (it is lower). And based on other information that I have seen, maybe even lower than in that data.
